# Unable to launch gatling 3.6.1 server

Tags: java, gatling

Unable to launch gatling and it fails with the following issue using JDK 14.0.2 or JDK 8 on a Mac | Ubuntu machine

```
./gatling.sh 
GATLING_HOME is set to /Users/foo/work/software/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.6.1
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Multiple garbage collectors selected
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Multiple garbage collectors selected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have set a `JAVA_OPTS` env var that defines a garbage collector algorithm and it conflicts with the one set in `gatling.sh`.
Edit one or the other to resolve the conflict.

Comment: BTW, will Gatling pick ZGC by default once Java 17 is out?

Comment: @GeorgeLeung Impossible, this would mean requiring Java 17. We still support Java 8... As much as we'd like to move forward and require Java 11, we're not in a position to force users to upgrade. Spring, Hibernate and maybe Netty are. But you can easily edit the launch script or the maven/gradle/sbt launchers to pick ZGC if you want.

Comment: I guess the launcher can intelligently detect and choose according to the Java version.

Comment: ZGC, Shenandoah, G1... Lots of possibilities with their pros and cons. We'll investigate them, and conduct benchmarks (AFAIK, those new GC tend to underperform on small-medium heaps and really shine on huge ones) when we'll upgrade.